# How define a trait alias for a slice of integers with extra functions?

Tags: rust, slice, traits

(This is a follow-up question to [an older question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74839321/2854284).)

In my project I want to be able to define functions (initially just copying a slice) over a generic slice that can be either `[u8]` or `[u32]`. I think that I have worked out one way for that to be done, by defining a trait and then implementing it for all combinations of `[u8]` and `[u32]` (the trait is aliased as [this answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26071172/2854284)):

```rust
pub trait GlkArray: GlkArrayCopy + GlkArrayInfo + Index<usize> + Sized {}
impl<T: GlkArrayCopy + GlkArrayInfo + Index<usize> + Sized> GlkArray for T {}

pub trait GlkArrayCopy<SRC=Self> {
    /** Copy a slice into this slice, must be the same length */
    fn set_buffer(&mut self, src: SRC);
}

impl GlkArrayCopy for &[u8] {
    fn set_buffer(&mut self, src: &[u8]) {
        self.copy_from_slice(&src);
    }
}

impl GlkArrayCopy<&[u32]> for &[u8] {
    fn set_buffer(&mut self, src: &[u32]) {
        const MAX_LATIN1: u32 = 0xFF;
        const QUESTION_MARK: u32 = '?' as u32;
        for (&value, target) in src.iter().zip(self.iter()) {
            // Convert non-Latin1 characters to question marks
            *target = if value > MAX_LATIN1 {QUESTION_MARK} else {value} as u8;
        }
    }
}

impl GlkArrayCopy for &[u32] {
    fn set_buffer(&mut self, src: &[u32]) {
        self.copy_from_slice(&src);
    }
}

impl GlkArrayCopy<&[u8]> for &[u32] {
    fn set_buffer(&mut self, src: &[u8]) {
        for (&value, target) in src.iter().zip(self.iter()) {
            *target = value as u32;
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to use these this new trait, it doesn't seem to either support slicing it, nor does it seem to know that the trait alias does provide the `GlkArrayCopy` function. I'm trying to implement it in a struct that borrows a `GlkArray` with a function that is given another:

```rust
pub struct ArrayBackedStream<'a, GA: GlkArray> {
    buf: &'a mut GA,
    len: usize,
    pos: usize,
}

impl<GA: GlkArray> ArrayBackedStream<'_, GA> {
    fn get_buffer(&mut self, buf: &mut GA) -> u32 {
        let read_length = min(buf.len(), self.len - self.pos);
        if read_length == 0 {
            return 0;
        }
        buf[..read_length].set_buffer(self.buf[self.pos..(self.pos + read_length)]);
        read_length as u32
    }
}
```

This produces these errors:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:71:13
   |
71 |         buf[..read_length].set_buffer(self.buf[self.pos..(self.pos + read_length)]);
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `usize`, found `RangeTo<usize>`
   |
   = note: expected type `usize`
            found struct `RangeTo<usize>`

error[E0599]: no method named `set_buffer` found for associated type `<GA as Index<usize>>::Output` in the current scope
  --> src/lib.rs:71:28
   |
71 |         buf[..read_length].set_buffer(self.buf[self.pos..(self.pos + read_length)]);
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `<GA as Index<usize>>::Output`
   |
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
note: `GlkArrayCopy` defines an item `set_buffer`, perhaps you need to implement it
  --> src/lib.rs:7:1
   |
7  | pub trait GlkArrayCopy<SRC=Self> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:71:48
   |
71 |         buf[..read_length].set_buffer(self.buf[self.pos..(self.pos + read_length)]);
   |                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `usize`, found `Range<usize>`
   |
   = note: expected type `usize`
            found struct `std::ops::Range<usize>`
```

I'm assuming that simply aliasing the `Index` trait isn't enough, and that I'd need to add one or more other traits to the alias, but I can't work out which ones. I've tried: `RangeBounds`, `Deref`, `AsRef`, `AsMut`, but none of them worked. Possibly it needs all of them at once? I didn't try that yet.

I also don't know if it will automatically find their implementations, or if I'll need to add more implementations for those traits.

My minimal example is here in the Rust Playground, the only code I didn't show above is the `GlkArrayCopy` trait which provides the `len` function. Which now that I think about it is probably another sign that the alias isn't complete, because ideally it might be able to identify that the slice provides its own `len`?

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8c1cb079e58b4dac59b9713de3439b46

Am I going in the right direction and just need to add more traits to my alias, or is this approach just completely wrong? Any advice will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to overload your `GlkArray` trait with all the functionality that slices already have. That is generally not a good idea because slices are very rich types with tons of useful functions that aren't all expressible in traits. I realize that your real code might be more complicated, but I want to break this down to the level of "I need slices to have a `set_buffer` method and then use it in my `ArrayBackedStream` type" and then you can hopefully go from there.

The `GlkArray` trait does nothing but define some super traits that slices already implement. So I'll just get rid of it. It makes your type strictly less powerful than slices. Another problem with it is that it doesn't even name the type of element it holds. That'll make it difficult to actually use.

The `GlkArrayCopy` trait actually does something, it defines the `set_buffer` interface. To make it a little more generic and less to type, I'll call it `SetBuffer`.

One big problem with your code is that you tried to implement `GlkArrayCopy` like this:

```
impl GlkArrayCopy for &[u8] {
    fn set_buffer(&mut self, src: &[u8]) {
        self.copy_from_slice(&src);
    }
}
```

The type of `Self` in that impl block is `&[u8]`, meaning that the type of `&mut self` is `&mut &[u8]`. That type is kinda useless (except for `swap`ping or `take`ing) because it doesn't actually allow us to mutate anything (which is why the code above doesn't even compile). Instead, when implementing methods for slices, you need the actual slice type which is `[T]` not `&[T]`. `[T]` doesn't have a known size, so we'll have to slightly alter `SetBuffer`:

```
trait SetBuffer<Src = Self>
where
    Src: ?Sized,
{
    fn set_buffer(&mut self, src: &Src);
}
```

We need to tell the trait that `Src` might not have a known size and then we take `src` by reference in the method, just like we take `Self` by mutable reference.

And now we can implement it:

```
impl SetBuffer for [u8] {
    fn set_buffer(&mut self, src: &[u8]) {
        self.copy_from_slice(src);
    }
}

impl SetBuffer<[u32]> for [u8] {
    fn set_buffer(&mut self, src: &[u32]) {
        const MAX_LATIN1: u32 = 0xFF;
        const QUESTION_MARK: u32 = '?' as u32;
        for (&value, target) in src.iter().zip(self.iter_mut()) {
            // Convert non-Latin1 characters to question marks
            *target = if value > MAX_LATIN1 {
                QUESTION_MARK
            } else {
                value
            } as u8;
        }
    }
}
```

To define your `ArrayBackedStream` type, instead of making it generic over some `Array` type, let's make it generic over the type of its elements and then just use a slice to store those:

```
pub struct ArrayBackedStream<'a, T> {
    buf: &'a mut [T],
    len: usize,
    pos: usize,
}
```

Because we're using slices, we get all the functionality you tried to get from super traits previously for free:

```
impl<T> ArrayBackedStream<'_, T> {
    fn get_buffer<U>(&mut self, buf: &mut [U]) -> u32
    where
        [U]: SetBuffer<[T]>,
    {
        let read_length = min(buf.len(), self.len - self.pos);
        if read_length == 0 {
            return 0;
        }
        buf[..read_length].set_buffer(&self.buf[self.pos..(self.pos + read_length)]);
        read_length as u32
    }
}
```

Note the slightly funky trait bound:

```
[U]: SetBuffer<[T]>,
```

which tells Rust that a slice of elements of type `U` needs to able to set a buffer of elements of type `T`, e.g. `[u8]: SetBuffer<[u32]>`.

Side note: a method called `get_buffer` probably shouldn't be modifying any buffers.

Lastly, if you have a type that is basically a slice with some data wrapped around it, it can be very useful to implement the `AsRef` and `AsMut` traits for it:

```
impl<T> AsRef<[T]> for ArrayBackedStream<'_, T> {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &[T] {
        &self.buf[..self.len]
    }
}

impl<T> AsMut<[T]> for ArrayBackedStream<'_, T> {
    fn as_mut(&mut self) -> &mut [T] {
        &mut self.buf[..self.len]
    }
}
```

Now you can get the data out of the stream as a slice and use all of slice's methods on it for free.

I want to re-iterate that it can be useful to have some sort of `Array` trait with a bunch of super traits (look at any linear algebra library) and maybe you have a use case for that, but it wasn't the one you showed.